# Formatting numbers in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, number-formatting, angularjs-filter

I have a variable in Angular.js that I should fill like that :

```
values.push({x: '' + d.x + 'h', y: d.y / 100})
```

d.x and d.y are numbers that I should display in a ndv3 multiBarChart.But I should format the numbers as if I have 2500, I obtain 2 500.How can I do it ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write Angularjs filters Example.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackk88888/7eBWP/23/)

**HTML File**

```
<div>
    <label >{{"4876931.19" | numberFilter}}</label>
</div>
```

**App Js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['filters']);
```

**Filter js**

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('numberFilter', [function () {
    return function (number) {
        if (!angular.isUndefined(number)) {
               var parts = number.split(".");
               var str = parts[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");         
               if(parts[1] !== undefined){
                   str+="."+parts[1];
               }
               return str;
        }
    };
}]);
```

*Updated Code*

Comment: this function is suitable if the number contains comma.How can I do if it doesn't contain comma?In fact I need a function that handles the two possibilities.

Comment: If the number contains a comma '.00' add.

Comment: can you explain more? If I have 5007899 , I should obtain 500 789 9.I shouldn't add 00 only to handle this case.

Comment: thanks for your response.Your updated code works but I when I use numberFilter with the currency filter like this:    {{(order.totalAmount) | currency | numberFilter }}, the symbole of currency disappear.

Comment: Yes, I did it.I have updated my post.Now I want to format my numbers directly from javascript.Is there a way to do it with a ndv3 multiBarChart?

Comment: Have you an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small Javascript function which parses the provided number and format it to the desired output:

```
function formatNumber(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;

    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = " " + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Calling this function with the provided number:

```
formatNumber(4876931.19) // output will be: 4 876 931.19
```

```js
function formatNumber(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;
    
    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = " " + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(formatNumber(4876931.19))
```